# Can't see parent's methods in derived class

Tags: c#, derived-class

I'm trying to extend a class, then use a method from base class, but i can't see it.

My Code:

```
class A {
    protected void Foo(){}
}

class B : A {}

class C{
    void Bar(){
         B b = new B();
         b.Foo();
    }
}
```

How could i use b.Foo in C?

Comment: Did you mean for `C` to inherit from `A` as well? If so, the code *still* won't compile. See http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/tags/protected/ for articles as to why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't.  Foo is a protected member function of class A, and as such can only be used from within class A, or from within a class that inherits from it.

```
class A 
{
   protected int x() {}
}

class B : A 
{
   void F() 
   {
      A a = new A();  
      B b = new B();  
      a.x();   // Error
      b.x();   // OK
   }
}
```

Comment: Well, in fact i'm trying to extend System.Windows.Shapes.Line with 2 more variable. The real code:     
    
    public class Edge : Line 
    {
        <my variables>

        public Edge(....)
        {
             ....
        }
    }


But when i use it, i can't see it's methods or fields, even if they public.

Comment: You'd think!  But this is actually ok.  Instantiations of a class within the same class have such priveleges.

Comment: I don't think you can use Line as a base class for your Edge class because it's sealed.  Look here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.shapes.line.aspx

Comment: @ZacAttack I didn't know that! I could've sworn it would use the public interface. I just tested it, and it works for both instances created in the function, as well as instances passed as arguments.

Comment: What you COULD do however is create a container class that has your variables and holds a member instantiation of the Line class.  That would get around your inheritance problem nicely.

Comment: @CheeseSucker Kind of bizarre huh?  It seems like it should break a rule somewhere, I know when I first saw it I double taked.

Comment: @gberes Awesome!  Good luck with your project :)

Answer (score 1):

You can only see `protected` method from the within the descendant classes.

`C` doesn't inherit from `B` so, by definition, it cannot see its protected methods.

Answer (score 0):

You must make the method `Foo` public.

```
class A {
    public void Foo() {}
}

class B : A {}

class C {
    void Bar(){
         B b = new B();
         b.Foo(); // Works
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to mark `Foo` with the `public` modifier rather than protected because C does not inherit B; it "uses" B.

See [here for more information](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6tcf2h8w%28v=vs.71%29.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Make it `public`. `Foo()` will only be visible to `A` and its derived classes (like 'B'). `C` is not a derived class of `A`.

Answer (score 0):

Because Foo is protected it's can't be seen to anything except derived classes.

To expose it you need to do:

```
class A 
{
    protected void Foo(){}
}

class B : A 
{
    public new void Foo()
    {
        base.Foo()
    }
}
```

Other answers have touched on this but none mention the use of the **new** keyword to expose the method with the same name, but different accessibility.